# Sorting a list in ascending and descending order

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of integers e.g.

**INPUT EXAMPLE**

```
4,7,9,8,20,56,78,34,2,76,84,98
```

I need to sort this list in a way that any number til 20 will be sorted in ascending order and above 20 will be sorted in descending order. So output will be :

**OUTPUT EXAMPLE**

```
2,4,7,8,9,20,98,84,78,76,56,34
```

I wrote a comparer for it. but now trying for more clean approach may be by using the existing tools like orderby.

Comment: Can you share the code you have? Does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using two sort groups:

```
list.OrderBy(i => i <= 20 ? i : int.MaxValue) // sort numbers less than 20 ascending; put numbers greater than 20 at the end
    .ThenByDescending(i => i)  // sort remaining numbers descending
```

Comment: `? 0 : 1` is unnecessary; you can just order on the boolean value.

Comment: @Servy: but then you have to use `OrderByDescending` or reverse the condition. Actually `0 : 1` is more readable.

Comment: @Servy True, but I don't like having to remember if `true` or `false` comes first, so I just use 0 and 1 so I don't get it wrong.

Comment: Good solution but I think It could be done with using two sort groups instead of three like this: `list.OrderBy(i => i <= 20 ? i : int.MaxValue).ThenByDescending(i => i);`. Right?

Comment: @S.Akbari Yes you could - the first sort would effectively move the higher numbers to the end.  Good catch.  I have edited the answer to show that.

Answer (score 4):

You can trivially do this using a custom comparer:

```
public class MyCustomComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    private readonly int _cutOffPointInclusive;

    public MyCustomComparer(int cutOffPointInclusive)
    {
        _cutOffPointInclusive = cutOffPointInclusive;
    }

    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x <= _cutOffPointInclusive || y <= _cutOffPointInclusive)
        {
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
        else 
        {               
            return y.CompareTo(x);
        }
    }
}
```

This sorts ascendingly when either value to compare is lower than or equal to the cutoff point (both to push the greater values to the top and to sort the values up till the cutoff point ascendingly), and descendingly when both are greater than the cutoff point (to actually sort those greater values descendingly).

Tested using:

```
var testData = new List<int>{ 4,7,9,8,20,56,78,34,2,76,84,98 };

testData.Sort(new MyCustomComparer(20));

foreach (var i in testData)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
7
8
9
20
98
84
78
76
56
34
```

See also http://ideone.com/YlVH8i. So I don't really think this isn't "clean", but just fine.

Comment: It is my first choice...but don't you think that on maintainability part...as any application will grow...these custom algorithm will lost somehow. Just curious to know the other thought :)

Comment: @AshishRajput FWIW When I have custom comparers for a specific type I usually make then private (or public if necessary) classes within that type.  That way they're associated wit the type and don't get "lost".  Granted your custom comparer is for an array, so that's not an option here, but it may be something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use two steps?

```
var bellow = originallist.Where(i => i <= 20).OrderBy(i);
var above= originallist.Where(i => i > 20).OrderByDescending(i);

var sorted = bellow.Concat(above).ToList();
```

Comment: Because that's about the most horrible performance you can get?

Comment: Yes, micro-optimisation is the most important thing in this question.

Comment: what about performance. It is just a snapshot of my problem, but my actual data is quite big

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič The algorithm of an expensive operation isn't a microoptimization.  Algorithmic level decisions are macrooptimizations.

Comment: @Henrik Where().Where().Concat(), for one.

Comment: @Henrik : the list is enumerated through twice where once would suffice. That's pretty much the only performance problem. In most use cases, no big deal.

Comment: @Falanwe yes, that's what I thought too.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] a = { 4, 7, 9, 8, 20, 56, 78, 34, 2, 76, 84, 98 };

var b = a.OrderBy(i => i > 20 ? int.MaxValue - i : i);
```

If possible, I recommend sorting in-place. For example ( can be improved )

```
Array.Sort(a, (i1, i2) => (i1 > 20 ? int.MaxValue - i1 : i1) - (i2 > 20 ? int.MaxValue - i2 : i2));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[Test]
        public void SortTill20AscRestDesc()
        {
            var src = new[] {4, 7, 9, 8, 20, 56, 78, 34, 2, 76, 84, 98};
            var expected = new[] {2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 20, 98, 84, 78, 76, 56, 34};
            var result = src
                .Select(
                    i => new
                    {
                        IsAbove20 = i > 20,
                        Value = i
                    }
                )
                .OrderBy(e => e.IsAbove20)
                .ThenBy(e => e.IsAbove20 ? int.MaxValue : e.Value)
                .ThenByDescending(e => e.Value)
                .Select(e=>e.Value);

            Assert.That(result.SequenceEqual(expected), Is.True);
        }
```

Comment: This isn't meaningfully different from the answer posted an hour ago.